# When would I use 飛行場【ひこうじょう】 over 空港【くうこう】 for airport？

Tags: word-choice

So my flashcards say 飛行場【ひこうじょう】 means airport.

But actual airports in Japan always use 空港【くうこう】, like 成田【なりた】空港【くうこう】.

What are the differences between these?

And in what situations (if any) would I want to use 飛行場【ひこうじょう】 over 空港【くうこう】？

Answer (score 13, accepted):

飛行場 refers to a small local airport with a short runway, often with no regular commercial airline service.  It is mostly for private use of small-size aircrafts.

空港 refers to a larger airport with longer runways that serves the general public.

Some (but not many) native speakers use the two words interchangeably in informal conversations.

Comment: In English it might be the same as the distinction between an airport and an airfield.